# Cannot use old slug - it just 301s to site home page

Tags: pages, redirect, slug, bug

Thanks in advance for any help guys,

For some reason my three pages stopped working, they just 301 to the home page. I think it may of been due to installing a plugin but I am not entirely sure.

I have since deleted the pages and re-created them, if I use the same slug they still 301 to the home page. However, if I change the slug to anything else they then work.  It's like the original slugs are reserved somehow.  But when i check the db there is only one post using the slug ie:

```
    SELECT count(*) FROM wp_posts where post_name = '$mySlugName';
```

I would expect if there was a conflict with the slug names that there would be more than one post using the name.

Other things I have tried:

- Disabling plugins
- Regenerating permalinks

I'm really not sure where to go with this now, may have to start debugging the core wordpress code base.

Cheers

Comment: Have you tried in multiple browsers?

Comment: I may be mistaken, but I believe WordPress keeps old slugs in options sometimes for SEO redirection. Maybe remove the old slug redirect or loop in your options table for `_wp_old_slug`

Comment: Thanks for the replies guys, I have tried mutliple browsers and clearing caches.  If behaves the same when I use wget on command line too.             I've looked for old slugs, but the following query returns 0 rows:        SELECT * FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE `meta_key` = '_wp_old_slug'

Comment: Have you tried testing in a fresh browser **with the problem plugin disabled** - you did after all suggest that this was the cause.

Comment: @TheDeadMedic Thanks for the reply, the problem still persists when I disable all plugins unfortunately

Comment: I have started to debug WP_Rewrite and the rule being matched is: [([^/]+)(?:/([0-9]+))?/?$] => index.php?name=$matches[1]&page=$matches[2]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem a few weeks ago, this is what solved it for me:

Went to Settings / Permalinks, switched to Plain and Saved.
After that I changed Permalink settings back to the previously used values and it worked.

Let me know if this fixes your issues.